# Hints on $\lambda^{d}(\alpha B)=|\alpha|^d\lambda^{d}(B)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $B \in \mathcal{B}^{d}$ and $\alpha\neq 0$

Any ideas on how to show:

$\lambda^{d}(\alpha B)=|\alpha|^d\lambda^{d}(B)$

My idea using "simple sets":

Let $B:=[a_{1},b_{1}[\times...\times[a_{d},b_{d}[$ this means:

Note without loss of generality $\alpha > 0$ otherwise switch intervals $[a,b[$ to $[\alpha b,\alpha a[$

$\alpha B=[\alpha a_{1},\alpha b_{1}[\times...\times[\alpha a_{d},\alpha b_{d}[$

Therefore $\lambda^{d}(\alpha B)=\prod_{i=1}^{d}(\alpha b_{i}-\alpha a_{i})=\alpha^{d}\prod_{i=1}^{d}( b_{i}- a_{i})=\alpha\lambda^{d}(B)$

Since $\{[\alpha a_{1},\alpha b_{1}[\times...\times[\alpha a_{d},\alpha b_{d}[\}$ is a $\cap-$stable generator of $\mathcal{B}^{d}$ it follows:

$\lambda^{d}(\alpha B)=|\alpha|^d\lambda^{d}(B)$ for any $B \in \mathcal{B}^{d}$

Comment: Hint: Show that the result holds for simple sets, then consider the class of sets such that it holds.

Comment: @Did So $\lambda^{d}(\alpha B)=\int_{\mathbb R^{d}}\chi_{\alpha B}d\lambda^{d}$ does not help? I am confused as to how to use your hint

Comment: No it does not. Re my hint, it has two parts. Let me suggest to first concentrate on the first part, and then to turn to the second part.

Comment: @Did I have edited my question, is it correct?

Comment: Yes, although you might be more explicit about how you deduce the result for the class of Borel sets from the result for the smaller class.